# Is there an existing method to lift ARMv7 [iPhone] binaries to LLVM IR?

Tags: llvm

I am trying to do some blackbox analysis on a iOS ARMv7 binary. It would be interesting to apply the LLVM analysis tools to such a binary, but I don't have source code. Is there a an existing lifter tool which could lift ARMv7 bytecode to LLVM IR?

Comment: what is a "lifter tool"? are there existing examples of such tools?

Comment: https://github.com/trailofbits/mcsema/blob/master/docs/UsingLibFuzzer.md